# Magento #nav with RGBA issue

Tags: css, magento, hex, nav, rgba

So I'm trying to add an RBBa background color to my navigation, however it gets pushed back behind an element if its not a solid color. Why is this? The markup is all correct and you can view the issue here : www.newsecuritytechnologies.com

Try and use the navigation at the top and it looks correct but is falling behind other elements. Is this because of the RGBa? If so, why?

Comment: ul#nav? Can't see a background-color definition in my Google chrome ...

Comment: @StefanBrendle I believe it is `#nav div`

Comment: @StefanBrendle I'm developing on chrome as well.

Comment: @StefanBrendle about line 517 on the styles.css is the code for the nav. BG-color is line 536

Answer (score 0):

that's true about RGBA if You use transparent You have to know that element under this will by show. You can change color of `.quick-access` maybe some gray color will be good. Another think is tha You should be carefull to use rgba, IE8 doesn't support rgba.

http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba

Comment: So in response to that, how would I get, a hex value, for example for that RGBa color. Obviously the color (1,52,158) is the RGB value which can be easily reformatted for HEX, but how do I extract a color from the RGBa value?   EDIT: The RGBa value is (1,52,158,.1)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this ended up being a bit deceptive!

You see, your links are the same colour as your blue banner on which they seem to be dissapearing, because the nav background is so opaque (and very very similar to the dark blue beneath) the dark blue of the intro block is drowning it out.

Amend this CSS to see what I mean, the links you think have dissapeared actually show up:

```
#nav ul li a {
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

You can also see this in effect if you select the last portion of the rgba value in firebug (or chrome developer tools) an increment it using the up or down arrow keys, you should notice that the closer you get to the value being 1 the more prominent the nav will become over the blue bar.

I hope this makes sense.